# Solve the equation $3x+7=6$ in $\mathbb{Z}_{13}$

Tags: abstract-algebra

The title is exercise 2.2 in *The Fundamental Theorem of Algebra*.

The hint for the problem is: *Find the value of $\frac{1}{3}$ in $\mathbb{Z}_{13}$*

> (please realize that my knowledge of the subject is what I read in Chapter 2)

I have gotten that $x = -\frac{1}{3}$.

I know that $\mathbb{Z}_{13}$ is the integers modulo 13.  Thus $x \equiv n \pmod{13}$? for some integer n,  $0\le n < 13$.

Thus for $x – n = km$ for some integer $k$, with $m \neq 0$ and an integer.

How does m divide $(x-n)$, when $(x-n)$ is not an integer, if $x = -\frac{1}{3}$????

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The notation can indeed be confusing the first few times one encounters in. When one says $x=-1/3$ in the context of $\mathbb{Z}_{13}$, it is simply short-hand for saying that $x$ is some number from $0$ to $12$ such that $-3x \equiv 1 \pmod{13}.$ So remember that $x$ is not the usual real number $-1/3$, but we use this notation because it *behaves* like $-1/3$ would, in that $-3x=1$ in $\mathbb{Z}_{13}.$

Comment: thanks.  I was getting very lost because of the (1/3), a fraction.  I have looked on wikipedia and rutgers, but neither used method you explained. thanks alot.

Comment: @MaoYiyi You are welcome. For some practice, you should find out what $1/4$ is in $\mathbb{Z}_7$ and what is $-1/2$ in $\mathbb{Z}_5$? Also see what is $1/2$ in $\mathbb{Z}_{16}.$ Is there more than one answer there?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** $\rm\ mod\,\ 3n\!+\!1\!:\ -1\equiv 3n\:\Rightarrow\:\dfrac{-1}3\,\equiv\, \dfrac{3n}3 \,\equiv\, n$

Answer (score 1):

What you could have done also
$$ 3x + 7 = 6\pmod{13} \implies 3x = -1 \pmod{13} \implies 3x = 12 \pmod{13}$$
 At this point it should be pretty easy!

Answer (score 0):

Note that $3x\equiv -1$ iff $3x\equiv 12$ modulo $13$. From there, it should be simple.

$x=-1/3$ only in the sense that it is the member of $\Bbb Z_{13}$ such that $3x\equiv -1$ modulo $13$. This is *not* the same as saying $x=-1/3$ in the sense of real numbers.

Comment: how is that 1/3? in mod 13?  Modular arithmetic doesn't have fractions.

Comment: True, there are no fractions, here. However, there **are** multiplicative inverses. Perhaps it would be better if the book had said "find the value of $3^{-1}$ in $\Bbb Z_{13}$", instead? Moreover, since $13$ is a prime number, then $\Bbb Z_{13}$ is a field, and so every non-$0$ element of $\Bbb Z_{13}$ has a *unique* multiplicative inverse. We can't do this in $\Bbb Z_n$ for general $n$.

Answer (score 0):

We look for an integer $x$ so that 3x=-1 mod 13. This is the same as $3x+1=0 \mod 13$ or $13 | 3x+1$. Now in this case we can just run through the integers $0\le x\le 12$ to find the answer $x=4 \mod 13$.

Comment: You might point out that just "running through" the integers $2\leq p-1$ isn't a great plan for general primes $p$, as $p$ could be rather large....

Answer (score -1):

Hint:  what is $-1 \pmod {13}$ in the normal set of representatives $0 \le n \lt 13$?